# Oracle - how to join multiple rows in vertical oriented table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

Let's say I have two tables like those:

```
table1:
-----------------
| someId | value|
|--------|------|
| 1      | 2    |
| 2      | 3    |
| 3      | 4    |
-----------------

table2:
-----------------------------------
| someId | type | value1 | value2 |
|--------|------|--------|--------|
| 1      | 2    | hello  |        |
| 1      | 3    |        | 2      |
| 1      | 4    |        |        |
| 2      | 4    |        |        |
-----------------------------------

table1.someId = table2.someId
```

`table2` is vertical, so multiple rows of this table (based on `someId`) refer to `table1.someId`.

Now I need to obtain **count** of rows from `table1` for which `table1.value=?` AND (`table2.type=2` and`table2.value1=?`) AND (`table2.type=3` and `table2.value2=?`) joined on `table1.someId = table2.someId`.

This is the query I have right now (it is parametrized and parameters for `value`, `value1` and `value2` are passed from a client):

```
select count(case when t1.value = ? then 1 end) from table1 t1
  inner join
  (select value1.someId from
    (select someId from table2 where type = 2 and value1 = ?) value1
    inner join
    (select someId from table2 where type = 3 and value2 = ?) value2
    on value1.someId = value2.someId
  ) t2
  on t1.someId = t2.someId;
```

Example query:

```
select count(case when t1.value = 2 then 1 end) from table1 t1
  inner join
  (select value1.someId from
    (select someId from table2 where type = 2 and value1 ='hello') value1
    inner join
    (select someId from table2 where type = 3 and value2 = 2) value2
    on value1.someId = value2.someId
  ) t2
  on t1.someId = t2.someId;
```

Is there any other way how to achieve this instead of multiple `select`s joined by `inner join`s? (In reality, I have to search by three `types` from `table2`).

Running example with correct result (updated example from Michael Buen):
[db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jbM55AwrAhisGHvfxexMuC/3)

Thank you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Output is just a number (count of rows from table1 with all the conditions applied). Please, look at Michael's comment.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ don't have `Text to DDL` though. For that, I uses this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/ Paste an example data on its `Text to DDL` and it will generate the DDL for you. However, db-fiddle.com don't have Oracle (might be licensing issue). So if need to test Oracle, just use dbfiddle.uk instead.

Comment: your query is SQL standard enough, that it will run on both Oracle and Postgres, hence I used db-fiddle.com for your data and result

Comment: What does "is vertical" mean? How is the output a function of input?  Why are those 2 queries there? PS Clarify via edits, not comments. Put relevant fiddle text in your post to make it self-contained. If you got an answer please post it as an answer, don't put it in your question or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is write a custom pivot for table2 groping by someid before join with table1:

```
with s (someId, type, value1, value2) as (
select 1, 2, 'hello', to_number(null) from dual union all
select 1, 3, null   , 2 from dual union all
select 1, 4, null   , null from dual union all
select 2, 4, null   , null from dual)
select someid,
max(case when type = 2 then value1 end) type2_value1,
max(case when type = 3 then value2 end) type3_value2/*,
max(case when type = 4 then value1 end) type4_value1
max(case when type = 4 then value2 end) type4_value2*/
from s
group by someid;

    SOMEID TYPE2 TYPE3_VALUE2
---------- ----- ------------
         1 hello            2
         2
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for quick response. The query is parametrized (value, value1 and value2 are passed from client). Please, see my updated question. Thank you.